# Matlab non-linear, multi-parameter curve fitting issue

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, least-squares

I am trying to implement a routine for fitting electrophoretic data from my experiments.

The aim is to derive kinetic parameters for the interaction of biomoecules from the relative areas of peaks in the electropherogram, based on the areas of the peaks in the dataset.

Since all relevant differential equations are known and since the set of equations has an analytical solution, as described here:

[Analytical solution manuscript](http://www.yorku.ca/skrylov/Publications/Anal_Chem_2004_v76_pp1507-1512.pdf)

I set about entering the relevant equations (6, 8, 13, ... from the referenced manuscript) in matlab.

The thus created function works and I can use it to simulate electropherograms of interacting species.

Obviuously, I now would like to use the function to fit experimental data and retrieve the parameters (8 in total, Va, Vc, MUa, MUc, k, A0, C0, baseline noise).

Some of these will obviously be correlated. Example values might be (to give an idea of their magnitude):

```
params0 = [ ...
           8.44E-02; ... % Va
           1.25E-01; ... % Vc
           5.32E-05; ... % MUa
           8.87E-05; ... % MUc
           4.48E-03; ... % k
           6.06E-01; ... % A0
           3.00E-00; ... % C0
           4.64E-03 ...  % noise
         ];
```

My problem is, if I supply experimental data and try something like lsqcurvefit:

```
[x,resnorm,residual] = lsqcurvefit(@(param,xdata) Electropherogram2(param,xdata,column), params0, time, ydata,lb, ub);
```

I often get very poor results because I either run out of iterations, I hit some (obviously poorly fitting) local minimum or whatever...

Only if I tinker a lot with the starting values and the allowed intervals (i.e. because I know likely values through other experiments) do I end up with more or less decent fits, but even then, fits are not as good as reported in the original manuscript (fig. 3).

The authors of that manuscript used Excel solver and were kind enough to provide the original data used in Fig. 3 but still I cannot seem to end up with fits as good as theirs without nearly literally supplying the nearly correct starting values.

I am not experienced enough to know what I could tweak to make this process less trial-and-error.

Would something like the global optimization toolbox help me?

Any tips are welcome...

Comment: These problems are very nasty.  With 8 free variables, the problem becomes very difficult, small changes in the initial values make a big difference in the final values.  What kinds of tests have you run?  By that I mean are you able to design your test so that some terms become inconsequential?  Any attempt to solve this by pushing the data into a solver is likely not to work.  I would be interested to hear if your tests can decouple some parameters.

Comment: Hey macduff, your comments seem to confirm my fears. The authors of the referenced papers did a lot of work on this but present it as if these kinds of fits could be easily applied. However, I think they also just set the parameters "by eye" and based on independent data and let the lsq routines take care of only the final tuning... MUa and MUc (diffusivities) cannot be accurately determined independently without going trough extreme amounts of trouble... A0 and C0 are essentially unknown since you would need k (and related Kd) to know them at equilibrium.

Comment: If any of the parameters are linear, you have a [separable](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18E03/index.html?product=OP&solution=1-18E03) problem. Fitting linear and non-linear parameters separately can dramatically improve convergence. Also, the global optimization toolbox can help.

Comment: Another approach which is slow but does find a global minimum is simulated annealing. (see http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/simulated-annealing.html)

Comment: Do you have a single functional relationship - the electropherogram signal as a function of time - that depends on these 8 parameters? Or do you have multiple functional relationships - i.e. multiple electropherogram signals?

Comment: Oh, one final thought: have you tried fitting your simulated electropherograms? This can be a way to get a feel for how well different optimization techniques will work in the ideal case of no experimental error. You can also try to get a feel for how important the starting values are (but with 8 parameters this might be hopeless).

Comment: I take it back, I have another comment :-) Are you sure that this data can really constrain all 8 parameters, and that the global minimum is much lower than all of the local minima? Looking at the data in that paper, it really only looks like there are 5 "features" for the curve fitting to work against: the locations of the two peaks, the width of each peak, and slope in between them.

Answer (score 1):

In the mentioned paper ("Analytical solution manuscript") it is implied that the free optimization parameters are five (Va, Vc, MUa, MUc, k) and not eight because the (Aeq/Ceq) ratio can be computed from their representative equations, eq. 8 for Aeq and (obviously) eq. 6 for Ceq.

In my opinion, what's even more troubling is the appearance of the following products in the model, comprised of the free optimization parameters:

1. k and Va in eq. 12
2. MUc and Va in the equation for epsilon_A in eq. 12
3. MUa and Vc in the equation for epsilon_A in eq. 12

In general, non-linear optimization algorithms have a legitimate trouble in optimizing the free parameters when pairs of the latter appear as products in the non-linear model.